# Can't login to my Drupal website admin!

Tags: users

I can't login My drupal website (D 7.23) now.
I have changed the password and tried to login back, but still the problem exists. After I reset the password by using the one time password and can log in, but when we log out and try again to login, it will be a failed one.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nice article on drupal.org on recovering administrator's password. Here is the [link](https://drupal.org/node/44164)

Specifically, you would probably be using one of the two commands below:

Drush can generate a one-time login link.

```
drush uli
```

Reset password

```
drush upwd --password="givememypasswordback" admin
```

Answer (score 0):

When you follow the reset password link, make sure you set a new password and save your account page at `/user/[uid]/edit`

Comment: Yes i saved and i got a save message !

Comment: but the problem still exist

Comment: It could be a caching problem. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?